# scrollable textview in listview?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, scrollview

In android ,I want to customize  list view such a way that each row contain a textview and a an edittext also  a specific row contain a text view which contain  large text , so i want to make it as a scrollable textview similar to text area ,basically my aim is to create a registration page which contains large number of fields

Can anybody give me any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

As in a previous post of mine:

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a **custom adapter** that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

*Please* learn to google:

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Answer (score -2):

Don't use a ListView. Use a ScrollView containing a layout (LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) that contains all the views of your registration form.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Specifically he wants to create a ListView with some layout and an edittext and a textview. The Listview has to be scroll-able, so it makes sense.

Comment: The OP said "basically my aim is to create a registration page which contains large number of fields. Can anybody give me any idea how can I implement it?". He's looking for a way to solve this need - I don't see how my answer isn't valid or helpful.